# Change the background color of a view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swift5, xcode11

[image]

I want to make a simple form and change the background color of a text field, but Xcode provide me `.background(background: View)`, etc option but not `.background(Color()`).

Comment: Post the code, not image.

Answer (score 6):

`Color` is conformed to `View`. So you can use it like any other `View`. The issue with your code is you add `cornerRadius` **inside** the `background` modifier. It should be out like this:

```
TextField("Title", text: .constant("text"))
    .background(Color.red)
    .cornerRadius(5)
```

Comment: Nope - doesn't work for TextField. Correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62848276/change-background-color-of-texteditor-in-swiftui

Comment: This is the answer to the question. The title is misleading. @AntonínKarásek

Answer (score 3):

Try below code.

```
struct ContentView: View {

   @State var name: String = ""

   var body: some View {

       VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {

           Text("NAME").font(.headline)

           TextField("Enter some text", text: $name)
           .padding(.horizontal , 15)
           .frame(height: 40.0)
           .background(Color(red: 239/255, green: 243/255, blue: 244/255))
           .overlay(
               RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                   .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.3), lineWidth: 1)
           )
       }.padding(.horizontal , 15)
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var name: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter some text", text: $name)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting answers it is best to explain how your answer solves the question askers issue.

Comment: This is not the correct solution either since when you then click on the TextField the text area will have the same color.