# Why doesn't the background of my TextField change to the colour I've set?

Tags: swiftui

[image: TextField remains white even when background colour is set]

Why does the background of the TextField remain white after I've set it to use a defined colour? Why does it still overlay white?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var search: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.baseColour
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    TextField("Search for a profile... ", text: $search)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        .background(Color.textFieldBarColour)
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30)
                .background(Color.textFieldBarColour)}
```

Comment: You must post the code and not an image on StackOverflow. Look up this answer, it says the same and you might need to use .overlay()

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727341/change-the-background-colour-of-a-textfield-in-swiftui-with-xcode11-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do with plain textfield style, like below (your custom colours just replaced with known for demo)

[image: demo]

```
TextField("Search for a profile... ", text: $search)
    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
    .padding(8)
    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(Color.yellow))
```

Comment: Setting the text field style to `.plain` doesn't seem to remove the default background on watchOS. 